# killing contextA's session from contextB on same weblogic server

Tags: session, weblogic

Hi I have 2 wars on same machine. Let's say warA and warB.

When user is in /warA I have the sessionId of the  same user in /warB. And i want to kill this session.

My aim is if user in /warA ,  i want to quarentee that the user session in /warB is killed.

Some can say write a servlet that kills /warB 's session and call it from /warA.

The reason i can't do this is, there is an agent(Oracle Access Manager) infront of /warB that do authentication part and don't let me call warB's servlet directly.

So is there any other way to do my job?

Edit:

I found this. Does OAM Agent breaks this request? Is it a simple request or a request between contexts?

servletContext.getContext("/warB").getRequestDispatcher("/logout");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two war files are deployed to the same WLS server, I believe this is the default behavior.  WebLogic stored session id in the cookie named jsessionid, if you do not configure a different cookie name in the `weblogic.xml`. Thus if a user login war2, the jsessionid cookie from war1 will be overwritten and the session with war1 will not be maintained.

Comment: Hi Surge. Two war's cookie name that holds jsession id are different. 
warA's jsessionid cookie name is jsessionidforwara and warB's jsessionid cookie name is jsessionidforwarb. I had configured them from weblogic.xml before. So this should work i think :)